# empty space when trying to add a point to highcharts chart dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I am trying to add points to spline chart dynamically via web socket , but the first point I add will not be connected to the one before it (as shown in the image)

[image: chart image]

[Video Example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9iFQ.gif)

the code sample:

```
chartWebSocket.onmessage = function (event) {
   chart.series[0].addPoint([x, y], true, true);
}
```

thank you,

Comment: You cannot add a point o the middle of the graph but only to the end. Anyway, your code does not allow to reproduce the issue. Can you make a live example? Your starting point can be this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/66xrsaew/ I

Comment: i'm not adding the point in the middle of graph , i edited the post to show u a video sample -  @morganfree

Comment: Could you please provide a configuration of your chart and show what values are drawn on it? Normally, `addPoint` should work as expected. As it was mentioned in the above comment, you can extend the following fiddle with your logic and data: http://jsfiddle.net/66xrsaew/